# why does isinstance check for abc.Sequence return False for custom classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, types, sequence

I've read in the `abc` python module docs that a `Sequence` is something that implements the following: `__getitem__`, `__len__`, `__contains__`, `__iter__`, `__reversed__`, `index`, and `count`.

Yet, when I run the following example it yields false:

```py
from collections import abc

class Sequence():
    def __getitem__(self):
        pass
    def __len__(self):
        pass
    def index(self):
        pass
    def count(self):
        pass
    def __contains__(self):
        pass
    def __iter__(self):
        pass
    def __reversed__(self):
        pass

print(isinstance(Sequence(), abc.Sequence)) # False
```

When I was doing similar stuff for `abc.Collection` or `abc.Reversed` to play around I got the results I expected, for example I created a dummy class that implements `__contains__`, `__iter__`, `__len__` and it was in fact detected correctly as an instance of `abc.Collection`.

Do you have any idea what's wrong with `Sequence`?

EDIT 1:

```py
from collections import abc
class CustomIterable:
  def __iter__(self):
    pass
print(isinstance(CustomIterable(), abc.Iterable)) # True
```

even though my custom iterable is not from `abc` it still is recognized as `Iterable` because it implements `__iter__` special method.

Comment: I think that it has something to do with [def runtime_checkable](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/typing.py#L1689).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question today.

From what I can gather, `collections.abc.Iterable` implements a custom `__subclasshook__()` method, whereas `collections.abc.Sequence` does not:

```
# _collections_abc.py

class Iterable(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    __slots__ = ()

    @abstractmethod
    def __iter__(self):
        while False:
            yield None

    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
        if cls is Iterable:
            return _check_methods(C, "__iter__") # True if __iter__ implemented
        return NotImplemented
```

What this means is that if a class `Foo` defines the required `__iter__` method then `isinstance(Foo(), collections.abc.Iterable)` will return `True`:

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

class Foo:
    def __iter__(self):
        return []

assert isinstance(Foo(), Iterable)
```

I'm not sure why `collections.abc.Iterable` implements a custom `__subclasshook__()` method but `collections.abc.Sequence` does not.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom `Sequence` class is different from the `abc.Sequence` class so `isinstance` will return false.

If you're looking for True, your custom class needs to inherit from `abc.Sequence`:

```
class Sequence(abc.Sequence):
   .....
```

Comment: Please see my edit in the first message (I couldn't figure out how to format multiline code in the comments).  So, my custom iterable is indeed recognized as `Iterable`, I thought that's how these things worked under the hood. Example like mine seemingly has no importance, because if I implement `__iter__` and `__getitem__` I will be able to use it in for loops and so on, but it might become problematic for example in static code analysis. If I implement my own type, which I think is a sequence, but actually is not, and then run mypy on it it may break I think.

Comment: And even if your example is true for sequences, then why does my example from edi1 behave like that? `CustomIterable` is not `abc.Iterable` and it doesn't inherit from it, yet it is in fact `abc.Iterable`. Any ideas how these things work?